# JavaScript scrolling events, fade in place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, fade

I'm trying to pin some divs in place and fade them in and out as a user scrolls down. My code looks like this so far:

```
$(window).on("load",function() {
    var fadeDuration = 500;
    function fade() {
    // compute current window boundaries
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        windowBottom = windowTop + $(window).innerHeight(),
        focusElt = null;

    // find our focus element, the first visible .copy element,
    // with a short-circuiting loop
    $('.imgdiv').toArray().some(function(e, i) {
        var objectTop = $(e).offset().top;
        if ((objectTop >= windowTop) && (objectTop <= windowBottom)) {
            focusElt = e;
            return true;
        }
            console.log(focusElt);

    });

    // obscure all others
    $('.focus').not(focusElt)
        .removeClass('focus')
        .fadeTo(fadeDuration, 0);

    // focus on our focus element; if was the previous focus, nothing
    // to do; but if it wasn't focus / wasn't showing before, make
    // it visible and have class focus
    $(focusElt).not('.focus')
        .addClass('focus')
        .fadeTo(fadeDuration, 1);

}
fade(); //Fade in completely visible elements during page-load
$(window).scroll(function() {fade();}); //Fade in elements during scroll
```

});

[Here's the corresponding fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amoeboar/ztog0nq7/) that almost does what I'm looking for, but instead of the green "Fade In" blocks moving upward and fading, I want them pined in place near the top of the window. As the "IMG DIVs" move past them they will fade and reappear with each new "IMG DIV". Here, I'm focusing on the particular green block and fading it when it becomes the focus element. Instead, what I need to do is, focus on the IMG DIV blocks, add a "pinned" class to the green blocks when they reach the top of the page, and fade the green blocks in and out.

Does anyone have any advice?

Part 2 of my question is how to do this with native JavaScript, and not rely on jQuery's dependency.

Comment: You probably have a good reason to not use jQuery, but note it is going to be a lot harder. The other thing is there are probably jQuery scroll plugins out there that may do what you want. Good luck!

Comment: ok, let's get this working in jQuery and then worry about native javaScript later. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so lets split your first issue into two issues :)

First of all, you want to (in general) do something when some element becomes visible in the viewport and when it becomes invisible. So, basically, all you need is function like that:

```
watchElementIsInViewport(
    $('.imgdiv'),
    doSomethingWhenElementAppearedInViewport,
    doSomethingWhenElementOutOfViewport
);
```

You know, that when element becomes visible, you want to show some other element. When element becomes invisible, you want to hide that related element. So now, define those two functions:

```
function doSomethingWhenElementAppearedInViewport(element) {
    // retrieve text related with the element
    var $copy = $(element).next('.copy');

    // fade it in
    $copy.fadeTo(500, 1);
}

function doSomethingWhenElementGotOutOfViewport(element) {
    // retrieve text related with the element
    var $copy = $(element).next('.copy');

    // fade it out
    $copy.fadeTo(500, 0);
}
```

What about `watchElementIsInViewport`? There is no magic inside, only logic you already created, but decoupled from showing of finding elements.

```
function watchElementIsInViewport($elements, elementAppearedInViewport, elementGotOutOfViewport) {
    var currentlyVisible = [ ];    
    // retrieve positions once, assume it won't change during script is working
    var positions = getVerticalBoundaries($elements);

    function _scrollHandler() {
        var viewportTop = window.scrollY;
        var viewportBottom = viewportTop + window.innerHeight;

        $elements.each(function(index, element) {
            var elementPosition = positions[index];
            /* if you wish to check if WHOLE element is in viewport
             * var elementIsInViewport = (elementPosition.top >= viewportTop) &&
             *   (elementPosition.bottom <= viewportBottom);
             */
            var elementIsInViewport = (elementPosition.top < viewportBottom) &&
                (elementPosition.bottom > viewportTop);
            var elementIndexInCurrentlyVisible = currentlyVisible.indexOf(element);

            // if element is visible but was not visible before
            if(elementIsInViewport && (elementIndexInCurrentlyVisible === -1)) {
                elementAppearedInViewport(element);

                currentlyVisible.push(element);
            // if element is not visible but was visible before
            } else if(!elementIsInViewport && (elementIndexInCurrentlyVisible !== -1)) {
                elementGotOutOfViewport(element);

                currentlyVisible.splice(elementIndexInCurrentlyVisible, 1);
            }
        });
    }

    // initial check & update
    _scrollHandler();

    // check & update on every scroll
    $(window).on('scroll', _scrollHandler);
}
```

And that's all. [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/erykpiast/b7qnrsrz/106/).

Comment: thank you very much for the thoughtful response! please read the updated question, what's missing is that by default, all but the first green "copy" divs should be invisible. also, the topmost div is meant to pin in place and fade in and out as the IMG DIVs exit the top of the screen. does that make sense?

Comment: hey, just change CSS for `.copy` elements (`position: fixed` seems to be enough) as well as the logic of calculating `elementIndexInCurrentlyVisible`.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, can you provide an example of using the position: fixed property? when I try it the divs disappear completely.

Comment: You have to set `top` and `right` properties to place fixed element in top left corner of the viewport. See: http://jsfiddle.net/erykpiast/b7qnrsrz/107/